# Saving a tmp file in django

Tags: python, django

I want to save a tmp file in django. The file will be immediately deleted, but I need to save it out temporarily to transfer it. I tried creating a folder named `'tmp'` in my app, but I'm getting a permission error that will not allow me to save to that directory in django. Where and how can I most easily save a temp file in django?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125859/how-do-you-fix-the-following-django-error-type-ioerror-value-errno-13-pe

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Pythons [standard library "tempfile"](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html). There you should find what you need.