# Django Error (13, 'Permission denied')

Tags: django, windows, permissions

I'm been working on this Photo Organizer and Sharing App Part I at http://lightbird.net/dbe/photo.html. I'm trying to generate a thumbnail and when I do . I get this error.

I have Windows Vista.

```
  IOError at /admin/photo/image/add/
  (13, 'Permission denied')
  Request Method:   POST
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/photo/image/add/
  Django Version:   1.4.3
  Exception Type:   IOError
  Exception Value:  (13, 'Permission denied')

  Exception Location:C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in save, line 1399
  Python Executable:C:\Python26\python.exe
  Python Version:   2.6.0
  Python Path:  

  ['C:\\djcode\\mysite',
  'C:\\Python26\\python26.zip',
  'C:\\Python26\\DLLs',
  'C:\\Python26\\lib',
  'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win',
  'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk',
  'C:\\Python26',
  'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages',
  'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']

  Server time: Sun, 10 Feb 2013 23:49:34 +1100
```

My `models.py` is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from string import join
from django.core.files import File
from os.path import join as pjoin
from tempfile import *

import os
from PIL import Image as PImage
from mysite.settings import MEDIA_ROOT


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Save image dimensions."""
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        im = PImage.open(pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
        self.width, self.height = im.size

        # large thumbnail
        fn, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
        im.thumbnail((128,128), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb2" + ext
        tf2 = NamedTemporaryFile()
        im.save(tf2.name, "JPEG")
        self.thumbnail2.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf2.name)), save=False)
        tf2.close()

        # small thumbnail
        im.thumbnail((40,40), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb" + ext
        tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
        im.save(tf.name, "JPEG")
        self.thumbnail.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf.name)), save=False)
        tf.close()

        super(Image, self).save(*args, ** kwargs)

    def size(self):
        """Image size."""
        return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name

    def tags_(self):
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.tags.values_list()]
        return str(join(lst, ', '))

    def albums_(self):
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.albums.values_list()]
        return str(join(lst, ', '))

    def thumbnail(self):
        return """<a href="/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media/%s" height="40" /></a>""" % (
                                                                (self.image.name, self.image.name))
    thumbnail.allow_tags = True
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["title"]

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["tag"]

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "title", "user", "rating", "size", "tags_", "albums_","thumbnail", "created"]
    list_filter = ["tags", "albums"]
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()
```

The problem is here:

```
from django.core.files import File
from os.path import join as pjoin
from tempfile import *

class Image(models.Model):
    # ...

    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Save image dimensions."""
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    im = PImage.open(pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
    self.width, self.height = im.size

    # large thumbnail
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
    im.thumbnail((128,128), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb2" + ext
    tf2 = NamedTemporaryFile()
    im.save(tf2.name, "JPEG")
    self.thumbnail2.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf2.name)), save=False)
    tf2.close()

    # small thumbnail
    im.thumbnail((40,40), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb" + ext
    tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
    im.save(tf.name, "JPEG")
    self.thumbnail.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf.name)), save=False)
    tf.close()

    super(Image, self).save(*args, ** kwargs)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Have you created the 'images' folder on `MEDIA_ROOT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like django doesn't have the permissions it needs to access your `MEDIA_ROOT` folder.

Have a look at your `MEDIA_ROOT` settings in your settings.py file. Then check the permissions on the folder (something like `ls -lsa /path/to/media_root` from a bash shell). Make sure the user running django as write permission to the folder.

Also, as asermax points out, make sure you have created an images directory within your MEDIA_ROOT.

Have a look at the documentation for [serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/) particularly the section on [serving other directories](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories)

UPDATE

Perhaps it's [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125859/how-do-you-fix-the-following-django-error-type-ioerror-value-errno-13-pe). Try replacing `im.save(tf2.name, "JPEG")` with `im.save(tf2, "JPEG")`

Comment: I'm using window vista atm . I located my media folder which is at MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/djcode/mysite/photo/media' and I added full control over the permission. The error still appears . What should do ?

Comment: asermax , is this suppose to be my image folder C:/djcode/mysite/photo/media'

Comment: No, your image folder should be at C:/djcode/mysite/photo/media/images. You've said in the upload_to parameter of your models.py that you're uploading images to this directory. As asermax rightly points out, you will need to create the folder if you haven't already.

Comment: Oh ok . I created it but when I upload an image , the error still appears. Thank you guys for trying to help me . I think I'm lacking in knowledge in the area of  making django application. The only knowledge I consume is through the Google python classes and django book from chapter 1 to 7 . Then I tried to jump into lightbird django example but it's proven to be hard . @Aidan Ewen , I see you have great knowledge of django , How should a beginner like me succeed in learning django . Is it through making django example apps? And trying to pick bits and pieces or going back to master phython

Comment: I've added an update - see if that solves your problem. Don't be discouraged. You're doing fine. These things just take time. If you haven't already done the official django tutorial then you could try that - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/. Just be persistant and keep going. You're going to hit problems, but that's where you'll learn the most.

Answer (score -1):

set SELinux permisions 
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied
 take a look to this, it may be there the solution